# Codeigniter: Undefined variable: + Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to show users full name and photo profile on the nav bar (just like social networking site navbar) using codeigniter 2.1.4,

This is my model:

```
function saya(){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    return $this->db->get_where('UserAplikasi', array('UserID' => $session_data['userid']))->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
function index(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $data['saya'] = $this->m_saya->saya();
        $data['isi']   = "administrator/home/home_view";
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('administrator/template');
    }
    else{

        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

And view:

```
<?php echo $saya->NamaLengkap; ?>
```

That code works in some page, but in the other page its error **Undefined variable: saya and Trying to get property of non-object**
Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Ok, I just edited my question, sorry, could you help me now, please?

Comment: What view is that? It says `$saya` is not defined, so it looks like you load it from a different controller action than `index`. This would explain why that variable is not defined.

Comment: Thats from view home.php (function index), model m_saya.php, and controller home.php

Comment: I see, but do you load that view in any other part of your application? Or do you use that code in places that don't require the user to be logged. That could explain the "Undefined variable" error. I'm sorry, this is all I can say based on the code you're showing.

Comment: possible `$data['saya']` is empty. try `var_dump($data['saya']);`

Comment: I am using template.php as the main view (template) and including other view in it. I want to call the "NamaLengkap" data from template.php. When I called from "home" controller, it works properly, but when i call for example "book" controller, it is error.

Comment: what are you getting in `$data['saya']`? It is possible for empty string.

Comment: i got my data when i wrote var_dump($data['saya']);

Comment: The only way you would get that error is if you aren't passing those two items in the magic `$data` array from your controller

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was only loaded m_saya on the home controller, it's fixed now. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: @mituw16 - You should put your comment in as an answer, and it should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you would get that error is if you aren't passing those two items in the magic `$data` array from your controller